# Application hangs while trying to perform asynchronous operations with SQLite in Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, asynchronous, async-await

In a Xamarin app I'm having an intermittent issue, where it will close out of nowhere. After examining the code and output log, and googling around a bit, I figured that there was too much data load on the UI thread. Summarizing, this works fine:

```
public List<T> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return Connection.Table<T>().Where(expression).ToList();
}
```

However, the application hangs while trying to call an async version of the method:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return await AsyncConnection.Table<T>().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
}
```

I also tried to be fancy, but the result was the same:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetList(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        { return Connection.Table<T>().Where(expression).ToList(); });
}
```

It is used like so:

```
var lst = GetList(x => x.EntityName.Equals(entityMobile.EntityName)).Result
```

Comment: SQLite.Net.Async-PCL 3.1.1 basically

Comment: That one has not been updated in 3|4 years and is not longer maintained, it was forked from `sqlite-net-pcl` which is still maintained. You should change to it and try again: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net as it uses the latest SQLite native libs...

Comment: What do you mean "obviously I'm using the Result object whenever I try to call the async methods"? It sounds like you're already aware of [the deadlock problem](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) but are causing it anyway? And "obviously" makes it sound like `Result` is the right thing to do?

Comment: @StephenCleary Glad my hubris gave it away. I'm gonna edit the question and give a shout out to your article in the answer once I'm done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary), this situation incurs a deadlock. His [blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) goes into detail and presents two solutions. I opted for the latter in my case (just stick to async all the way):

```
public MyDAO
{
    // ...
    public async Task<List<T>> GetListAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    { 
        return await AsyncConnection.Table<T>().Where(expression).ToListAsync();
    }
}

public MyViewModel
{
    private MyDAO _myDAO;
    //...

    public async void DoAsyncStuff()
    {
        var myList = await _myDao.GetListAsync(x => x.EntityName.Equals(entityMobile.EntityName));
    }
}
```

This is a simplification of what I actually have, but I suppose it will do as a broad example. More of these can be found in his article.